# Install Glade 3.8.5 in english (Windows)

Tags: windows, gtk, glade

Does anyone know how can I change the language of Glade 3.8.5 to English from my native language, Greek? Thank you. (OS Windows)

Comment: A partial answer I found myself and it's the brutal force method. If I delete the folder  Glade Interface Designer Gtk+ 2\share\locale\el  it automatically falls back to EN by default which is nice but it's got to be a better method.